# Retain count while copying

Tags: ios, memory-management, copy, retaincount

I am quiet new with memory management. I know my question has already been discussed on StackOverflow. But I would like to know the answer to understand it completely. My question is:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
secondArray = [firstArray copy];
```

what will be retain count for firstArray and the secondArray after copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 for each. `firstArray` is holding the pointer to `firstArray`. When you call `secondArray = [firstArray copy];`, the contents of `firstArray` are copied to a new memory location and `secondArray` will point to that location. This means that `firstArray` and `secondArray` will be pointing to separate memory locations (and are different objects), although they have the same data. Therefore, they each have a retain count of 1.

Comment: And don't forget to mention that the retain count of the original `secondArray` will be 0 and it will be released.